# Path in jar - Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, file, jar, path

I try to get a file which is in my jar.
Here is my jar ->
[image]

But when i it, my app doesn't find the file which is in the jar.

> TownGraph.loadGraph(getClass().getResourceAsStream("./"+selectedFile + ".txt"));

"./"+selectedFile + ".txt" = ./town10.txt

Comment: The file is expected in the package subfolder of the class. So if the code line is called in the class with `package foo.bar;`, move the `.txt` files in the JAR into `foo/bar/`.

Comment: It works! I moved the wrong file ... Thank you !